# Book recommendation for Apollo program, very specific

Tags: apollo-program, reference-request

I'm looking for a book about the Apollo program that specifically focuses on the logistics of the mission, as if it were a case study in project management. How were records kept, goals tracked, teams formed and coordinated, etc?

Comment: A boatload of Gantt charts, for the most part. You have to read the whole contents of NASA's history office pubs - see the https://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/249 list on Meta. Plus books written by NA and Grumman folks.

Comment: @DeerHunter could you be more specific? I looked through the list at Q249 and didn't see much that looked promising in terms of my particular interest. Where did you read about the "boatload of Gantt" charts?

Comment: Thomas J. Kelly - Moon Lander: How We Developed the Apollo Lunar Module. Wash., D.C, Smithsonian Books, 2001. My recollections were wrong, however - it was not only Gantt charts but also PERT (Larry Moran's group at Grumman).

Comment: Also, http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4102/contents.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This NASA technical report seems to correspond to your focus:

[Project management in the Apollo program: An interdisciplinary study](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19720025304)
Drucker, Pooler, Wilemon, Wood.
Publication Date: Jan 01, 1972
Document ID: 19720025304

> Findings concerning project management in the NASA Apollo program are
>   presented. The Apollo program in the context of the total NASA
>   organization is examined along with the nature of project management
>   and the manner in which project managers functioned in the Apollo
>   program. The utilization of the in-house technical competence in the
>   support of the Apollo program, and the formal and informal
>   relationships between Apollo managers and the contractors are
>   discussed.

There is a list of references that seems also interesting (appendix B, starting page 165).

Answer (score 2):

A brace of studies (intentionally made community wiki):

- Stephen B. Johnson. The Secret of Apollo: Systems Management in American and European Space Programs. Johns Hopkins Univ., 2002. [About the book](http://www.worldcat.org/title/secret-of-apollo-systems-management-in-american-and-european-space-programs/oclc/51504397)
- Thomas J. Kelly - Moon Lander: How We Developed the Apollo Lunar Module. Wash., D.C, Smithsonian Books, 2001. [About the book](http://www.worldcat.org/title/moon-lander-how-we-developed-the-apollo-lunar-module/oclc/44794944)
- [SP-4102 Managing NASA in the Apollo Era, NASA History Office](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4102/contents.htm)